# How to deserialize a json string in C# to the correct type, without deserializing twice

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, optimization, deserialization

I have the following code:

```cs
private async Task ResponseReceived(Stream inputStream) {
    using var reader = new StreamReader(inputStream);
    var message = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<BaseMessage>(message);
    Console.WriteLine($"Message Type Received: {obj?.EventType}");
}
```

To which all message classes extend. The `BaseMessage` class contains a single property: `EventType` that exists in every json string deserialization.

```cs
public class BaseMessage
{
    [JsonPropertyName("e")] public string EventType { get; init; }
}
```

The `EventType` provides information on the received json structure, to which I want to be able to trigger an event which publishes the correct object type based on the EventType.

The simplest solution I can think of is to do a switch case and deserialize a second time into the correct type, and then publish the event. However this poses 2 problems:

1. Switch case, requires coding for all the possible EventTypes (which is at least 20 currently, and could expand to many more).
2. Deserialization a second time, creates additional overhead in processing (both in memory and speed) where it is processing thousands of messages per second.

Is there a better way to optimize this either via a design pattern, or other way to handle it to avoid the above two concerns?  I am currently using .NET Core 5, and System.Text.Json (rather than Newtonsoft Json library).  I would prefer to stick with the Microsoft library, but am flexible if need to switch to Newtonsoft.

Answer (score 0):

for the first problem, if EventType contains also the namespace, you can deserialize with

```
var objBase = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<BaseMessage>(message);            
var objSpecific = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(message, Type.GetType(objBase.EventType));
```

so you don't need a switch.

for the second problem there is a solution, but it's breakable.
You can search for the class type inside the message.

```
var message = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new BaseMessage() { EventType = (typeof(A)).ToString() });
var typeString = Regex.Match(message, "\"e\":\"(.*?)\"").Groups[1];
var objSpecific = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(message, Type.GetType(typeString.Value));
```

if you are not forced I do not recommend it, because you can change the property name for example and you can find an error at run time or with a test.

Comment: Yeah, I was reading about that, unfortunately the incoming messages are an external source, I have no control over the incoming json.  So for example `EventType` will be some string like 'aggTrade' or 'trade'.
As for the second part: I considered some kind of string search method (as you described), but that I am not sure (without doing some benchmark tests), would be any better than double deserialization for overhead.

Comment: you can use a dictionary with eventype and your class.

Comment: I'm struggling with: doing a regex search and dictionary lookup being more efficient than double deserialization.  (I mean, I haven't tested it for speed, and I will try implementing it and test, but it doesn't seem any more efficient)

Comment: I don't think that serialize two times bring you at a huge effort. But depends on how the classes are big and how many message you have per seconds.

Comment: The messages are not big (anywhere from 60 - 300 bytes), the classes are just regular POCO classes (and as such I might just make them structs rather than classes as they are simple models with no functionality anyhow)... That said, there can easily be hundreds or into thousands per second, which is where my concern is for double deserialization.  While it is simple enough to deserialize, store the data in the BaseClass and then deserialize again when it knows what the concrete type, I was hoping there was a way to avoid that overhead.